# GNU Makefile, use a variable containing the dependent directories

Tags: unix, makefile

I am trying to create a Makefile
I have a Makefile variable containing dependent directories like

```makefile
DEPDIR := temp foo bar
```

I need the absolute path of each directory. So, I wrote a rule:

```makefile
DIRS := $(foreach dirs, $(DEPDIR), $(shell find $(HOME) -name "$$dirs"))
```

and I also tried:

```makefile
DIRS := $(notdir $(foreach dirs, $(DEPDIR), $(shell find $(HOME) -name "$$dirs")))
```

But variable `DIRS` in both case is empty.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using `find` for this is completely wacky.  There may be directories elsewhere in the directory tree with the same name, and anyway, presumably, the ones you want are in the current directory.

If they can be nested within other directories, running `find` *on the current directory* might make some sense, but you are probably simply looking for

```
$(patsubst %,${PWD}/%,$(DIRS))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea why did you write double `$`: `$$dirs`. Try this:

```makefile
DIRS := $(foreach dir, $(DEPDIR), $(shell find $(HOME) -type d -name "$(dir)" ))
```

Consider narrowing down the search criteria, since `$(HOME)` by definition can contain anything.

I guess you will not argue that it'd be better to keep track of the project dependencies using a dedicated directory. And there are many ways to build such kind of directories(generating symlinks, downloading/extracting compressed packages, cloning repositories, using package managers etc.). Therefore, I'll suggest the following pattern as well.

```makefile
MAKEFILE_PATH := $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
PROJECT_DIR := $(dir $(MAKEFILE_PATH))
DIRS := $(realpath $(addprefix $(PROJECT_DIR)deps/, dir1 dir2 dir3))
```

Here we extract filename of the current makefile from [`MAKEFILE_LIST`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html#index-MAKEFILE_005fLIST-_0028list-of-parsed-makefiles_0029), then store its absolute path in `MAKEFILE_PATH` variable. Then the directory part of the path to the makefile is stored in `PROJECT_DIR`. By means of [`addprefix`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#index-addprefix) we prepend `$(PROJECT_DIR)/deps` to the front of each dependent directory(`dir1 dir2 dir3`). Then we resolve symlinks, and construct canonical absolute names for the dependent directories, then store them in `DIRS`.

Comment: Is it me or is using `find` for this kind of crazy? How about addprefix and realpath/abspath?

Comment: @hobbs, I don't like `find` here either. I've just answered the question.

Comment: here temp, foo and bar can be anywhere in our setup, not in the current directory. that's the reason I used find. If any better solution would be appreciated

Comment: @NisargaRavindra, if it works, then accept the answer.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov: can you update your answer to include the proper (abspath/addprefix) solution, so that other readers coming across this don't get tempted to use 'find'?   The find is in fact a really bad solution, as there may be files/folders with the same name in the `$(HOME)` directory, which would cause things to break...

Comment: The double `$$` makes sense inside a `Makefile` to pass a single dollar sign to the shell; but yeah, that's not what's going on here.